# control mbed with python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, rpc, mbed

I want to control the mBed controller with python 2.7 
I tried this code as start

```
from mbedrpc import *

serdev = '/dev/tty.usbmodemfa122'

mbed = SerialRPC("/dev/tty.usbmodemfa122", 9600)

x = DigitalOut(mbed, "LED1")

x.write(1)
```

It always shows me this  error

```
File "/Users/Desktop/testRPC/mbedrpc.py", line 78, in __init__
   self.ser.setBaudrate(baud)
AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'setBaudrate'
```

Could someone help me please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DroneKit: Failed to connect to /dev/tty.usbmodem1411 : 'Serial' object has no attribute 'setBaudrate'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602168/dronekit-failed-to-connect-to-dev-tty-usbmodem1411-serial-object-has-no-at)

Comment: Indeed looks like a duplicate. Can you verify whether switching to pySerial 2.x via `pip install "pySerial>=2.0,<=2.9999` works?

Comment: Thank you that's helped me. Now I don't have any error but the code doesn't work means the led isn't activated.
Have you any suggestion ??

Comment: Please put it in a new question.

Comment: ok thank you very much