# TinyOS not compiling/uploading to TelosB mote

Tags: upload, tinyos

I'm running into a problem attempting to upload the "blink" app onto the motes. I can't seem to run the command `make telosb reinstall bsl,/dev/ttUSB0` or `make telosb reinstall` while in the `apps/Blink` directory, which is preventing me from moving on with my project. I've tried as a user, superuser, and as root. I've outlined below the responses from variable commands. [Running Ubuntu 16.04, TinyOS 2.1.2, ncc version 1.4.2, nescc version 1.3.6]

(A)With root and the `make telosb` command I get back:

`mkdir -p build/telosb
    compiling BlinkAppC to a telosb binary
ncc -o build/telosb/main.exe  -Os -fnesc-separator=__ -Wall -Wshadow -Wnesc-all -target=telosb -fnesc-cfile=build/telosb/app.c -board= -DDEFINED_TOS_AM_GROUP=0x22 -DIDENT_APPNAME=\"BlinkAppC\" -DIDENT_USERNAME=\"root\" -DIDENT_HOSTNAME=\"liam-Latitude-E\" -DIDENT_USERHASH=0x9236fe46L -DIDENT_TIMESTAMP=0x59384a62L -DIDENT_UIDHASH=0xdc08609fL  BlinkAppC.nc -lm
    compiled BlinkAppC to build/telosb/main.exe
            2538 bytes in ROM
              56 bytes in RAM
msp430-objcopy --output-target=ihex build/telosb/main.exe build/telosb/main.ihex
    writing TOS image`

(B)With regular user and the `make telosb` command I get back:

`mkdir -p build/telosb
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create build/telosb/ident_flags.txt: Permission denied
/home/liam/tinyos-main/support/make/ident_flags.extra:13: recipe for target 'ident_cache' failed
make: *** [ident_cache] Error 2`

(C)With a super user and the `sudo make telosb` command I get back:

`make: *** No rule to make target 'telosb'. Stop.`

(D)With root and the `make telosb reinstall` command I get back:

`cp build/telosb/main.ihex build/telosb/main.ihex.out
    found mote on /dev/ttyUSB0 (using bsl,auto)
    installing telosb binary using bsl
tos-bsl --telosb -c /dev/ttyUSB0 -r -e -I -p build/telosb/main.ihex.out
MSP430 Bootstrap Loader Version: 1.39-goodfet-8
Mass Erase...
Transmit default password ...
Invoking BSL...
Transmit default password ...
Current bootstrap loader version: 1.61 (Device ID: f16c)
Changing baudrate to 38400 ...
MSP430 Bootstrap Loader Version: 1.39-goodfet-8
Mass Erase...
Transmit default password ...
Invoking BSL...
Transmit default password ...
Current bootstrap loader version: 1.61 (Device ID: f16c)
Changing baudrate to 38400 ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/tos-bsl", line 1918, in <module>
    main(0);
  File "/usr/bin/tos-bsl", line 1843, in main
    speed=speed,
  File "/usr/bin/tos-bsl", line 1218, in actionStartBSL
    self.actionChangeBaudrate(speed)            #change baudrate
  File "/usr/bin/tos-bsl", line 1345, in actionChangeBaudrate
    self.serialport.setBaudrate(baudrate)
AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'setBaudrate'
/home/liam/tinyos-main/support/make/msp/bsl.extra:45: recipe for target 'program' failed
make: *** [program] Error 1`

(E)Whereas with a regular user and `make telosb reinstall` I get back:

`cp build/telosb/main.ihex build/telosb/main.ihex.out
cp: cannot create regular file 'build/telosb/main.ihex.out': Permission denied
/home/liam/tinyos-main/support/make/msp/msp.rules:92: recipe for target 'setid' failed
make: *** [setid] Error 1`

I have been all over the internet and online forums and haven't found a fix yet. I researched around (D) and found that perhaps python 2 might have changed the name of 'setBaudRate' variable. I'm not sure how to change that either.

Thank you for your time and help!

edit: added ncc and nescc versions.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602168/dronekit-failed-to-connect-to-dev-tty-usbmodem1411-serial-object-has-no-at) stack overflow answer is applicable to TinyOS.

So it turns out that pyserial 3.0.1 is not compatible with the TinyOS app, Blink. I'm fairly certain that pyserial 3.0.1 came with the package for TinyOS.  To fix this, use the command `sudo pip install "pySerial>=2.0,<=2.99999"`. For me, it kicked back:

`The directory '/home/liam/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/liam/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pySerial<=2.99999,>=2.0
Installing collected packages: pySerial
  Found existing installation: pyserial 3.0.1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (pySerial) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling pyserial-3.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pyserial-3.0.1
Successfully installed pySerial-2.7`

But the blink app still uploaded and worked fine.